General electromagnetic equation from Coulomb's law
Can we define the differential charge as the sum of (current × infinitesimal time) and (charge density × differential volume) where current is the partial derivative of charge w.r.t time and charge density is the partial derivative of charge w.r.t volume?

Consider the Jefimenko equations. As you can see, the electric field is described by $\rho$ and the current density.

Related: Can Maxwell's equations be derived from Coulomb's Law and Special Relativity?
